# material ui input type number reset incorrect value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have controlled component with material-ui `<OutlinedInput />` with `type='number'` and want to clear it by button. But this component has self validation and if I typing something like '---8' or another incorrect number value, I can't clear input by button. How I can fix it ?

Example here:

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-p0kio?file=/demo.js)

code:

```
import React from "react";

import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";

import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";

export default function ComposedTextField() {
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(123);

  const handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    setNumber(value);
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setNumber("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl variant="outlined">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="component-outlined">Number</InputLabel>
          <OutlinedInput
            id="component-outlined"
            value={number}
            onChange={handleChange}
            label="number"
            type="number"
          />
        </FormControl>
      </form>
      <button onClick={clear}> clear input </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thnx reymon359 for answer, but it looks like hack. I decide to change input type on text and add this line to code:

```
value = value.replace(/[^0-9.\-+,]/g, '');
```

So it works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

It works with `setNumber('&nbsp');`. Try it in your code, hope it helps :)

Check out [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-solution-fho5i?file=/demo.js:494-500)

```js
const clear = () => {
  setNumber('&nbsp');
};
```